# How to push a page's custom field data as a value within a template file?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Long story short.  I'm trying to expand the functionality of a portfolio template.  It currently can only handle one page.  I can duplicate the template, relying on custom fields to pull in specific portfilio items (the theme uses custom post types).

So, here's the bit from my portfolio-template.php:

```
   $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => 'ao',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
```

So, I want to create a new page, select the portfolio template, then define a custom field on that page that will pass on the meta_value to the portfolio-template.php

So it would look like this instead:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => 'PULL_VALUE_FROM_CUSTOM_FIELD',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
```

With "PULL_VALUE_FROM_CUSTOM_FIELD" being the bit that I can't figure out.  Sorry if my vernacular is code_crude, I'm new at this!

EDIT:  Adding in the full code of the template

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_value' => 'ao',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $portfolio_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : 

        echo '<div id="primary" class="hfeed">';

        while( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) : $portfolio_query->the_post();

        // styles
        $style = 'zilla-' . get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_style', true);
        $media_pos = 'zilla-' . get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_media_position', true);
        $width = ( $media_pos == 'zilla-media-center' ) ? 940 : 600;

        // project url
        $portfolio_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_project_url', true);
        if( !empty($portfolio_url) ) 
            $portfolio_button_copy = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_project_url_copy', true);

        // determine which media to display
        $portfolio_display_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_display_gallery', true);
        $portfolio_display_video = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_display_video', true);
        $portfolio_display_audio = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_display_audio', true);

        // grab everything else
        $custom_bg = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_display_background', true);
        $portfolio_caption = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_portfolio_caption', true);

    ?>

            <?php zilla_page_before(); ?>
            <!--BEGIN .hentry-->
            <div <?php post_class( $style . ' ' . $media_pos ) ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php zilla_page_start(); ?>

                <div class="hentry-inner">

                    <!--BEGIN .entry-media -->
                    <div class="entry-media">

                        <?php 
                        if( $portfolio_display_gallery == 'on' ) {
                            $gallery_layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_zilla_gallery_layout', true);
                            $slideshow = ( $gallery_layout == 'slideshow' ) ? true : false;
                            $size = ( $media_pos == 'zilla-media-center' ) ? 'portfolio-full' : 'portfolio-index';
                            zilla_gallery( $post->ID, $size, $slideshow, $slideshow );
                        }

                        if( $portfolio_display_video == 'on' ) {
                            $embed = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_zilla_video_embed_code', true);
                            if( !empty( $embed ) ) {
                                echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($embed));
                            } else {
                                zilla_video( $post->ID, $width );
                            }
                        }

                        if( $portfolio_display_audio == 'on' ) {
                            zilla_audio( $post->ID, $width );
                        }

                        ?>
                    <!--END .entry-media -->
                    </div>

                    <!--BEGIN .entry-content -->
                    <div class="entry-content">

                        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

                        <?php if( !empty($portfolio_caption) ) 
                            echo "<p class='zilla-caption'>" . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($portfolio_caption)) . "</p>"; ?>

                        <?php if( !empty($portfolio_url) && $media_pos == 'zilla-media-center' ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($portfolio_url); ?>" class="more-link"><?php echo $portfolio_button_copy; ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                        <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'zilla').'</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                        <?php if( !empty($portfolio_url) && ( $media_pos == 'zilla-media-left' || $media_pos == 'zilla-media-right' ) ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($portfolio_url); ?>" class="more-link"><?php echo $portfolio_button_copy; ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>

                    <!--END .entry-content -->
                    </div>

                </div>

            <?php zilla_page_end(); ?>
            <!--END .hentry-->
            </div>
            <?php zilla_page_after(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <!--END #primary .hfeed-->
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>

    <div id="content">
        <!--BEGIN #post-0-->
        <div id="post-0" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e('Error: No Portfolios Found', 'zilla') ?></h2>

            <!--BEGIN .entry-content-->
            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e("Sorry, but no portfolios have been created.", "zilla") ?></p>
            <!--END .entry-content-->
            </div>

        <!--END #post-0-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's happening before the `$args`? You need [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), but a `$post->ID` is necessary, hence the need for the context of code snippet. :::: And +1 for the well structured Question, something difficult to see in newbies ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the feedback, I added in the full template code, though I'm assuming you're just wanting the first bits.

Comment: Yes, it was just to make sure what was before and after, answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Before the Loop, you can access the global variable `$post`, which in case of `single.php` and `page.php` will represent that very post type (post/page/cpt) object that will be displayed by the template file.

If not mistaken, when used in `category.php`, for example, it will grab the first one.

So, in the case in question:

```
<?php
global $post;
$the_meta = get_post_meta( 'custom_field_name', $post->ID );

if( !$the_meta )
    $the_meta = 'your_backup_solution';

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_value'     => $the_meta,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$portfolio_query = new WP_Query($args);
// et cetera
```